# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException a lot

Tags: android, android-activity

Im not gettin the following error fixed (logcat):

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-105
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
found to handle Intent { act=com.androidpeople.xml.parsing.appz }
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010):        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivit
yResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010):        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity
(Instrumentation.java:1384)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010):        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(A
ctivity.java:3190)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010):        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.j
ava:3297)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1010):        at com.androidpeople.xml.parsing.Splash$1.run(Sp
lash.java:30)
```

tried so much but maybe somebody sees the light.;)

Splash.java. No compile errors at any class. only on emulator the app crashes after splashscreen

```
package com.androidpeople.xml.parsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class Splash extends Activity {
    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 2000;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread splash = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int waited= 0;
                    while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)){
                        sleep(100);
                        if(_active){
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                }finally {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this , appz.class));
                    stop();
                }
            }
        };
    splash.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            _active = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

de appz.java is:

```
package com.androidpeople.xml.parsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class appz extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);
    }

}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.androidpeople.xml.parsing"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity
            android:label="Appz"
            android:name=".appz" />      
    </application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

With this atm getting the screen but instant crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you declared the activity in activity tag in manifest file.

**EDIT :**

Manifest File:

```
...
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        ...
        <activity
            android:label="Appz"
            android:name=".Appz" />            
    </application>
...
```

Comment: Stukje uit manifest
<activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".appz"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
               </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: So you already have defined your both activities in manifest and then also,you are getting this error?

Comment: heb dit gebruikt (name met kleine letter maar ok.. ) dan opent ie het nieuwe scherm maar crasht direct....

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have downloaded XML Parsing tutorial from Androidpeople.com site, and yes to solve the above issue, just check the AndroidManifest.xml file, whether you have declared activity or not.

```
 <activity
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:name=".appz">
      <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

As you are trying to implement Splash screen activity, this should be as a MAIN and LAUNCHER so apply intent-filter for this activity.

**FYI, whenever you declare any activity and use the same activity in your application, it must be declare inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.**

Comment: As per the comment he made on my answer,it seems that his launcher activity is Splash activity.I suggested the same as you did,but i think,it is not working for him although.

Answer (score 0):

You class `appz` should extend `Activity` - I assume it does that.

What is most likely to be the problem is that you haven't added it to the `AndroidManifest.xml` as it is stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Permissions):

> The ability to start a particular Activity can be enforced when it is declared in its manifest's  tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have called finish method  before calling the new intent 
         so it is missing the context  please use this code
 i have changed the order

```
     Thread splash = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                int waited= 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)){
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active){
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
            }finally {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this , appz.class));
               }
             this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
splash.start();
```